# input radio and input text on one line on different resolution

Tags: html, css

How can i get input radio and input text on one line always. They won't stay in the same line when i change resolution.

```
<fieldset>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="url" <?php checked( $this->options['shortcode_link_type'], 'url' ); ?> />
            <input type="url" name="shortcode_url" class="input-text" value="<?php echo $this->options['shortcode_url']; ?>" />
        </label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: why use fieldset and not div?

Comment: You want them to "always" stay on the same line, or not?

Comment: use float:left for the radio button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some people suggested, the usual in inputs its to use the float: left style in the radio input.

```
input[type=radio]{
    float:left;
}
```

However, I don't really like to use "float" in the styles due its side-effects. Also, I think it won't make it not to jump down when you change resolutions or make the windows smaller.

So I will write here some alternative suggestions:

1. you can use flexbox in the parent block:

   ```
   label{
      display: flex;
   }
   ```

   This would force both elements to be in the same line as long as you
   don't use the flex-wrap: wrap property. However, although flex is
   widely used nowadays, it might not be compatible with older
   browsers.
2. you can place the radio input in an absolute position:

   ```
   label{    
       position: relative;
   }

   input[type=radio]{
       position: absolute;
       right: -20px; 
   }
   ```

   this will make the radio always to be 20px after the label - to use
   20 was arbitrary for this example, you should use the number it fits
   more your needs, usually the width of the element with some extra
   space for margins. This has the con that the radio input will become
   its own entity and if something goes after this block, it might go
   on the top of it. You can fix that issue with the next suggestion.
3. use position absolute, but leave the proper padding in the right of
   the label:

   ```
   label{
       position: relative;
       padding-right: 20px; }

   input[type=radio]{
       position: absolute;
       right: 0;
   }
   ```

   this would solve the last method's con. - remember to adapt the
   padding from 20 to the number that suits your style
4. you can simply force the parent block to not wrap and its children
   to inline:

   ```
   label {
       word-wrap: no-wrap;
       white-space: nowrap
   }

   label input{
       display: inline;
   }
   ```

Those 3 options should force the input to not jump to the next line.

Ps: I should say, I find weird to use a label as parent of inputs, let alone 2 of them. Semantically speaking, the tag label is supposed to describe a what an associated input functionality is, and also to put the focus into that input when clicking to the label, not to wrap inputs... Also, the default style that the labels have might be messing with the default styling of the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can `float` your input fields.

```
input[type=radio]{
    float:left;
}

input[type=url]{
    float:right;
}
```